# Help me evaluate this integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$\displaystyle \int \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \mathrm dx$

I just can't seem to figure this one out. I tried integrating by parts but I'm stuck.

Comment: Letting $u=\ln x$ and $dv=1/x^2 dx$ seems to make the problem rather tractable.

Comment: Yes but the derivative of $lnx$ is not $\frac{1}{x^2}$ so I don't understand how I'd use substitution here. I need another variable to make it work it seems.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing integration by parts for u-substitution.

Comment: Ah! Why the heck didn't I get this problem. I thought I had tried both ways with both functions as u.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts is not u-substitution. You split the integrand into two parts, $u$ and $dv$. Choose $u$ so that it will simplify when you take it's derivative. In this case, $u$ simplifies when it is ln(x) and the derivative is 1/x .

$u = \ln(x)$

$du = (1/x)dx$

$v = -1/x$

$dv = (1/(x^2))dx$

$uv - \int{vdu} = (\ln(x))\cdot(-1/x)- \int{(-1/(x^2)) dx} = (-\ln x)/x - (1/x) = -(
ln x+1)/x$

Comment: Just putting formulas might answer the question, but I don't think that it helps to address the confusion.  Perhaps talk about why you choose these functions for your $u$ and $v$ as well as why this isn't $u$-substitution might help the person who asked the question more.

Comment: The answer's correct and it can be taken as hints for the OP to find out what's going on, as (s)he already knows what is integration by parts. The downvote is just unfair and out of place, imo. +1

Comment: Thank you. I understand my error now.